# get the color of a serie that is colorized naturally in xtrachart(devexpress 14.2)

Tags: charts, devexpress, xtrachart

i have some series that i have not specified any color for them and they are colorized naturally by xtrachart. how can i get the color of each of them when they are drawn in plot control?
i found that the color is stored in actual color property but i cant access it normally and i only can get it in debug mode in watch section.
how can i get the color?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [SeriesViewBase.Color](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsSeriesViewBase_Colortopic) Property to specifies the series' color.

code snippet:

```
((SideBySideBarSeriesView)series.View).FillStyle.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
((SideBySideBarSeriesView)series.View).Color = Color.Red;
```

From: [How to: Custom Draw Series](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2503)

> You can also implement custom drawing in charts when drawing its
>   series. To do this you should handle the
>   [ChartControl.CustomDrawSeries](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_CustomDrawSeriestopic.aspx) event, and then you're able to
>   change some drawing parameters using its event args.

**References:**
[DevExpress forum: series colour](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q241896)
[Changing colour of a series point at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ66221)
[c# devexpress piechart series point color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385739/c-sharp-devexpress-piechart-series-point-color-change)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
[get the color of a serie that is colorized naturally](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T239916)

Note that we had need to get the color that was automatically assigned to the series.